# Turn NSString into NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data

Instead of storing an ordered `NSArray` of `NSString` as an archived `NSData` property of an `NSManagedObject` I want to enjoy the power of an `ordered To Many relationship` to avoid the burden of updating positions whenever an object is moved, removed or added.

In an ordered to many relationship the resulting property is an `NSOrderedSet` containing the `NSManagedObjects`. I then need to create an `NSString` property on the `NSManagedObjects` available in the `NSOrderedSet` and access this property to access the string.

Can the `NSManagedObject` already be an `NSString` so that my `NSOrderedSet` would contain what looks like simple `NSStrings`?

```
NSString * string =
managedObject.orderedSetOfStringManagedObject.lastObject.stringPorperty;
```

become

```
NSString * string =
managedObject.orderedSetOfStringManagedObject.lastObject;
```

Comment: The response is no...The set contains managed objects and not strings. What's your goal? Does your title reflect your question?

Comment: ...and what could be the advantage of a similar shortcut?

Comment: do that shortcut on 3 levels and you'll see. but indeed it not necessarily something very important. It could be cool and I would enjoy being able to do that.